# WCF: How to find out when a session is ending?

Tags: wcf, session

I have a WCF application that is using sessions.

Is there any central event to get thrown when a session ends? How can I find out when a session is ending WITHOUT (!) calling a method (network disconnect, client crashing - so no "logout" method call)?

The server is hosted as:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false,
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
)]
```

Basically because it is using a callback interface.

Now, I basically need to decoubple the instance created from the backend store when the session terminates ;)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
class MyService : IService
{
    public MyService()
    {
        // Session opened here
        OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Closed += InstanceContext_Closed;
        // get the callback instance here if needed
        // OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>()
    }

    private void InstanceContext_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Session closed here
    }
}
```

The code won't work for Single/PerCall InstanceContextMode.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good description of instance context [here](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/23/understanding-instancecontext-in-wcf/)

Instance context derives from [CommunicationObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.aspx)

Communication object has a [closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject_members.aspx) event.

I have not done this myself, but in theory it should be possible to use this event to decouple from the backend store when the session closes, by hooking into this event.

Answer (score -1):

Set you're timeout values and create a PingService() method that fires just before the timeout elapses, this will reset the Send and Receive timeouts.

if you want to catch the timeout simply attempt a callback, if the attempt takes longer than the binding SendTimeout value (default is 1 min i think), then you'll throw a time-out error and you can process the disconnect.

There's no way to gracefully catch a disconnected user (browser crashes, power goes out, etc., etc., etc.)

Comment: bad answer - I already have that (ping per second etc.) - does not stop a client from going DEAD because of timeout on the network or power loss or something, and that is exactly what I want / need to catch (I.e. I need to know when the connection is dead / session is ended).

THere is also no browser involved (why the heck does everyone think a web service is a stupid boring website?). THere is no client side involved here at all - my question is 100% server side. -1.

Comment: You can try this:  callbackClient.opContext.Channel.State.